# What options to do I have when a freshly imaged computer can't see USB keyboard/mouse?

Tags: windows-7, usb, drivers, keyboard, mouse

I'm working with an HP Elitedesk 260 G2 Mini-desktop. Basically, it has USB 2 and 3, a VGA port and a RJ-45 port. I have a USB keyboard and mouse plugged into the USB 2 ports.

I pushed a Windows 7 image to it using my network boot solution, and it's now on the logon screen.

Normally, I have to wait a minute or two for a freshly imaged PC to see the USB hub and grab a driver for it, but for some reason this PC is refusing to bring up the keyboard and mouse, so I have no way to physically log in to finish up. I tried a different keyboard and mouse, but I have the suspicion that the PC isn't bringing up the USB hub itself.

Are there any methods I can use to log onto this? I tried [PsExec](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec) to get a shell, but the $ADMIN share is not enabled on this machine, so that's a no go.

Comment: are you certain the USB ports are active? it's possible they've been disabled in BIOS. If the Bios has a legacy emulation mode for USB, try enabling that.

Comment: I did have to switch from UEFI to legacy BIOS before I pushed the image, so I'll check really quick to see if there's anything there related to USB.

Comment: "Are there any methods I can use to log onto this?"  Use the on-screen keyboard...?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007  How do I use the on-screen keyboard when the mouse doesn't work?

Comment: Does your mobo have PS2 slots?

Comment: bahaha good point. :)   RDP or VNC in from another computer perhaps?

Comment: @EricF Nope, just USB plus some video options. This is a mini desktop. Here's a back view: https://i.imgur.com/r3gM8ky.png

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 No way to enable/install RDP or VNC without physical access.

Comment: but the keyboard works in your bios? You mentioned you could change things in the bios

Comment: @EricF Yes, keyboard does work in BIOS.

Comment: @StevenDavison Nothing in the BIOS options other than to turn ports on/off.

Comment: Is the machine old enough to have a PS2 port? could you try using a PS2 keyboard?

Comment: So if windows7 doesn't see it then that seems to be the culprit here. A few helpful suggestions here: https://www.sevenforums.com/hardware-devices/169387-usb-keyboard-not-detected.html

Comment: Yeah, you're pretty much screwed, outside of controlling it via GP or something. ;)   Out of curiosity, what happens when you boot into Safe Mode?   Did you use Sysprep to prepare the image ahead of time, or is it just a straight image of another computer? I'm thinking it maybe due to a conflict (vs. not having a driver).

Comment: One thing - I have a script that joins this to our domain, and the script just ran. I'm going to try and push out a GPO to turn on RDP.

Comment: Seems if you can get scripts to work, that is a good thing and very good way to do it

Comment: That worked! It's a little on the enterprise-side of doing things; not everyone who ends up in this situation will have a domain in their house, so if anyone has some eother creative solutions, I'll gladly upvote them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a way to gain remote access: My image included a script that automatically joins the computer to our domain. The script ran and the machine rebooted.

I then pushed out a quick-and-dirty [GPO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_Policy#Operation) to that computer which ran the following as a startup script:

`reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server" /v fDenyTSConnections /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f`

That turns on [RDP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Protocol), and I was able to log in as administrator and install the appropriate drivers.